# How to keep track of users making Stripe Payments

Tags: mongodb, stripe-payments

I'm currently trying to figure out a way for my MEAN stack application to keep track of which users have paid to grant them access to a certain portion of my webpage. I've considered several options: Stripe customer ID, MongoDB record, And HTML attribute I can update.

My mean stack keeps track of users by JWT, and it appears stripe assigns them their own customer ID which isn't ideal. Can it done with JWT as opposed to their forced cutomer ID?

MongoDB record. Which is what I'm thinking might be the best option. When a new user has been created, i'll give it an attribute of hasPaid = no. Then update the record of that customer when a payment is submitted. Then I guess run a script to set everyone back to unpaid each day?

HTML element/attribute. I don't know if this is even possible; but it would be cool to create a key that is carried during the HTML session after payment is received. If the person closers the browser then the session would be closed?

I'm looking for guidance on my 3 options to determine if they're the best solution. Also, if anyone has any suggestions as to alternatives, I'm all ears!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking generally, the most common approach would be the second one: use an attribute in your data model that indicates whether the user has paid/should be granted access. When a charge is created [0] successfully, update the model to indicate so, then filter access based on this attribute.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_charge

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Boolean` value in your user model.

```
    var UserSchema = new Schema({
     name: String,
     hasPaid: {type: Boolean, default: false} //set this false
    });
```

then in your REST API routes, the user buys the product; now set `hasPaid` to true

```
    // req.user._id is passport config 
    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, {$set: {"hasPaid":istrue}}).exec(function(err) {

     if(err) {
      throw err;
     }else {
      req.flash('success', 'Thank you for submitting the form.');

      res.render('charge', {
        layout: 'dash',
        user: req.user,
        success: req.flash('success')
      });
     }
    });
```

Now you can keep track of the users that purchased your products to grant them access to other parts of your site.

Stripe.js comes with [Checkout.js](https://stripe.com/checkout) which makes it even easier to use Stripe's service.

Copy and paste this into your html/jade/handlebars or view file. This will display a popup form to let the user type in his or her cc information.

```
    <form action="/charge" method="POST">
     <script
      src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
      class="stripe-button"
      data-key="pk_test_bla3hf&kc033"
      data-image="/square-image.png"
      data-name="Demo Site"
      data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
      data-amount="2000">
     </script>
    </form>
```

You will receive a token once the user presses submit that you grab on your server. From inside your REST API route, you can charge the customer:

```
   var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express

   // Create a charge: this will charge the user's card
   var charge = stripe.charges.create({
     amount: 1999, // Amount in cents
     currency: "usd",
     source: token,
     metadata: { 
      user: req.user._id, 
      email: req.user.local.email
     }
     description: "Example charge" //keep track by writing a description or you can use the metadata property Stripe has to offer in the charges object
    },function(err, charge) {
     if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
     // The card has been declined
     }else {

      res.redirect('/thanks-for-your-order');
      console.log('charge here ' + charge.id); //store the id 
      console.log('charge here ' + charge.invoice); //store the invoice
      console.log('charge here ' + charge.customer); //store the customer id

     }
   });
```

You can now track each order by storing the properties of the charge object in any model you wish.